# How to execute JavaScript method when clicking on an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a game for class and I have added a commenting system to go with it. I am now wanting to add the ability to report the comment.

I have added a column in the comments table called `report_active` and my idea was to set this to 1 when it is active (meaning it has been reported) and 0 when it isn't. Then just list in the adminCP all of the comments with an active report on them.

On the comments page I have added a `href` attribute like so:

```
<div style="float:right;"><a href="javascript:reportComment();">Report</a></div>
```

The JavaScript function for this is:

```
<script>
    function reportComment() {
var commentReport = confirm('Are you sure you want to report this comment?');
if (commentReport) {
    $.post("report_comment.php", {"CommentID": <?php echo $data->id; ?>}, function() {
    window.location.href="report_comment.php";
});
}
  </script>
```

I have included jQuery 1.9.1 at the top of my file.

The issue is when I click the report button it doesn't do anything, it doesn't even show the confirm message.

What I am doing wrong?

If anyone needs any other code then please say.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`, which would be more obvious if you formatted your code properly. [Please learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: You cannot use php in your javascript like this.

Comment: @Daniel: Unless that page is generated via a PHP script.

Comment: @FelixKling that was it, sorry yeah I copied and pasted it and didn't check it properly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yes "true", but considering the call comes from the HTML, how will be known what the id is. Assuming there are multiple comments.

Comment: Why would you post the commentId with ajax and then you redirect to the same page without a parameter. Are you sure this is what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onClick method. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp

So you you would have this:

```
<a onclick="reportComment();">Report</a>
```

Or even better scrap the a and just have it as a button.

```
<button onclick="reportComment();">Report</button>
```

Comment: While it's better to use the onclick attribute, it's not *needed*, and it doesn't have anything to do with problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your href needs to be "#"(or javascript:void(0)), and you need to add an onclick function to invoke your js call.

Here's your code in PLNKR:
[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/lCpLnBN3AWagedRBHRtb?p=preview)

Comment: While it's better to use the onclick attribute, it's not *needed*, and it doesn't have anything to do with problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very tricky to call JS code in href attribute, so please avoid it as much as possible. You can do **onclick=reportComment()** also but separation of content from behaviour/action is compromised. Its better to add click event handler on jquery for `<a>` tag

HTML

```
<div style="float:right;"><a href='#'>Report</a></div>
```

JS/Jquery

```
     $('a').click( function() {  
       var commentReport = confirm('Are you sure you want to report this comment?');
       if (commentReport) {
                   // Ajax Code
      }
      return false; 
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gc54k/

Comment: True, it's better, but has nothing to do with the OP's problem.